# Time Series parsing - PI Data

Tags: r, time-series, large-data

I have a very large time series data set in the following format.

```
"Tag.1","1/22/2015 11:59:54 PM","570.29895",
"Tag.1","1/22/2015 11:59:56 PM","570.29895",
"Tag.1","1/22/2015 11:59:58 PM","570.29895",
"Tag.1","1/23/2015 12:00:00 AM","649.67133",
"Tag.2","1/22/2015 12:00:02 AM","1.21",
"Tag.2","1/22/2015 12:00:04 AM","1.21",
"Tag.2","1/22/2015 12:00:06 AM","1.21",
"Tag.2","1/22/2015 12:00:08 AM","1.21",
"Tag.2","1/22/2015 12:00:10 AM","1.21",
"Tag.2","1/22/2015 12:00:12 AM","1.21",
```

I would like to separate this out into a data frame with a common column for the time stamp and one column each for the tags.

```
Date.Time, Tag.1, Tag.2, Tag.3...    
1/22/2015 11:59:54 PM,570.29895,
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:
   
  `cast(df,V2~V1,mean,value='V3')
                      V2    Tag.1 Tag.2
1  1/22/2015 11:59:54 PM 570.2989   NaN
2  1/22/2015 11:59:56 PM 570.2989   NaN
3  1/22/2015 11:59:58 PM 570.2989   NaN
4  1/22/2015 12:00:02 AM      NaN  1.21
5  1/22/2015 12:00:04 AM      NaN  1.21
6  1/22/2015 12:00:06 AM      NaN  1.21
7  1/22/2015 12:00:08 AM      NaN  1.21
8  1/22/2015 12:00:10 AM      NaN  1.21
9  1/22/2015 12:00:12 AM      NaN  1.21
10 1/23/2015 12:00:00 AM 649.6713   NaN`

cast is a part of reshape package
Bests,
ZP